# Can I create a field in django-model depending of an other?

Tags: django, django-models, model

I created a class Lesson, I want to give the ability to an admin to add 1, 2, 3 or more textfields and other fields. For now I do like that :

```
    class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    text1 = models.TextField(default="")
    text2 = models.TextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    text3 = models.TextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

But in admin side it's not really nice

Does it exist a way to define a first field : models.IntegerChoices where the admin choose 10 for example and it automatically generates 10 textfields and so generate 10 columns in database ?

Thank's for reading

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate multiple TextFields on the fly because it requires database migrations.

What you can do in a case like this is to define a `CustomModel` that holds a single `TextField` and then define a `ManyToManyField(CustomModel)` in `Lesson` which you can then add as many references to as you need.

[Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to define model like:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Text(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    lesson= models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in admin u can define inlines:

Your problem is similar to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin